# Kafka + Kubernetes + Helm + `/usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer`?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, confluent-schema-registry

How do I use the standard `kafka-avro-console-consumer` tool with Kafka running via the Confluent Helm Charts? The `confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0` image recommended for running cli utilities doesn't contain `kafka-avro-console-consumer`.

If I shell into the schema-registry pod to use `kafka-avro-console-consumer`

```
kubectl exec -it my-confluent-oss-cp-schema-registry-6c8546c86d-pjpmd -- /bin/bash

/usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server my-confluent-oss-cp-kafka:9092 --topic my-test-avro-records --from-beginning

Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 5555; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
sun.management.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 5555; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:480)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:262)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:452)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 5555; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 5555;

Sounds like you've enabled JMX as part of that container via the `KAFKA_JMX_PORT` variable.

If that's the case, you will need to temporarily override that by exporting (or `unset`) it within the shell session to a different value before running any other Kafka scripts

Comment: can you please give an example? I have the same error using solsson/kafka and I don't know how to overwrite. I've tried to change JMX_PORT to another values but still the same error

Comment: The variable is `KAFKA_JMX_PORT`. How you set it depends on the OS or how you run the processes (Docker, k8s, base-metal, etc)